# Is it can add viewgroup in addHeaderView method of listview？

Tags: android, listview, viewgroup

I use the below code to add viewgroup in addHeaderView method of listview:

```
 MyViewGroup myvg = new MyViewGroup(this);
 listView.addHeaderView(myvg, null, false);
```

But headerView can not display in listview. Is it can add viewgroup in addHeaderView method of listview？or it can not add viewgroup in addHeaderView？

Comment: can u post the MyViewGroup Code ?

Answer (score 1):

The header will be displayed after you the setAdapter invoked.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it seems that header is not visible because the View group you added is empty.
and also set adapter after adding header.